# RenderBox was not laid out: RenderOffstage#a7bf1 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Tags: flutter

- [image]

[image: The relevant error-causing widget was ExpansionTile]
(The relevant error-causing widget was ExpansionTile)
the error appears when I add the SubCategoryWidget

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to wrap the expanded widget in the SubCategoryWidget with sizedbox ,and I gave it height 100